# Hypergeometric distribution when K is unknown

Tags: distributions, hypergeometric-distribution, capture-mark-recapture

The probability to have $k$ white balls in a sample of size $n$ taken from an urn of $N$ balls with $K$ of them being white is equal to:
$$
P(k|n,N,K) = \frac{{{n}\choose{k}}{{N-n}\choose{K-k}}}{{{N}\choose{n}}}
$$
How to infer a probability when $K$ is not determined a priori.

In other words the question would be: What is the probability to have $k$ white balls in a sample of size $n$ taken from an urn of $N$ balls with an unknown amount of them being white (I only know for sure that $k$ are definitely white but it can be more).

Comment: Similar binomial question:   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123367/estimating-parameters-for-a-binomial/123748#123748

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137331/estimating-size-of-a-set-based-on-two-overlapping-subsets

Answer (score 6):

You can estimate $K$ using [method of moments estimator](http://www.randomservices.org/random/urn/Hypergeometric.html)

$$
\frac{k}{n} \approx \frac{K}{N} \implies \frac{N}{n} k
$$

or maximum likelihood estimator as described by Zhang (2009):

$$
\frac{N-1}{n} k
$$

for derivation and further details check the following paper:

> Zhang, H. (2009). [A note about maximum likelihood estimator in
>   hypergeometric distribution.](http://revistas.usantotomas.edu.co/index.php/estadistica/article/download/37/35) Comunicaciones en Estadística, 2(2),
>   169-174.

On another hand, it you want to define a distribution of $k$ white balls, drawn without replacement from the urn containing $N$ balls in total, while treating the total number of white balls $K$ as unknown, i.e. as a random variable, then you can define such problem in terms of Bayesian model, with [beta-binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) prior (in fact a [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior)) for $K$ (as described by [Fink, 1997](https://www.johndcook.com/CompendiumOfConjugatePriors.pdf) and 
Dyer and Pierce, 1993):

$$
k \sim \mathcal{H}(N,K,n) \\
K \sim \mathcal{BB}(N, \alpha, \beta)
$$

what follows to a beta-binomial posterior predictive distribution of $k$ parametrized by $N$, $\alpha' = \alpha + k$ and $\beta' = \beta + N-k$, and the posterior distribution of $K$ is

$$
f(K\mid k,N,\alpha,\beta) = {N-n \choose K-k}
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+K)\,\Gamma(\beta+N-k)\,\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+n)}{\Gamma(\alpha+k)\,\Gamma(\beta+n-k)\,\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+N)}
$$

If you want to assume that $K$ can be anything in the $[k, N-n+k]$ range, you can use uniform $\alpha=\beta=1$ prior. For further details check:

> Dyer, D. and Pierce, R.L. (1993). On the Choice of the Prior
>   Distribution in Hypergeometric Sampling. Communications in Statistics
>   - Theory and Methods, 22(8), 2125-2146.

You may also be interested in reading about [capture-recapture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture) method where you are interested in finding $N$, since it is closely related and follows the same logic.

Comment: How did you compute here the predictive posterior of $k$ (the beta-binomial parametrized by $N$, $\alpha'$, and $\beta'$)? I couldn't find any info about this in the references.

Comment: @pms sorry, forgot to add the link, now updated

Comment: Actually, I found and checked previously Fink's compendium, but I couldn't find there anything about the predictive posterior. In this case, the predictive posterior is a beta-binomial mixture of hypergeometric distributions, but you wrote here that it's the beta-bionomial with parameters $N$, $\alpha'$, and $\beta'$, so I'm wondering how did you figure this out; is this conclusion straightforward?

Comment: @pms have you checked the paper by Dyer and Pierce?

Comment: Indeed, in Dyer and Pierce there is an expression for marginal distribution of $k$ (their $m(x)$ at the top of page 2131), but it's not explained how it was obtained. I imagine it can be calculated by marginalizing hypergeometric likelihood over the beta-binomial prior, but this calculation looks a bit tedious at first sight. 
Btw. A small correction -- it should be $\beta'=\beta+n-k$ in your above answer. Everything else looks fine.

Comment: I know this post is getting old, but for the posterior distribution of $K$, shouldn't we be using $\alpha '$ and $\beta '$? If we use $\alpha$ and $\beta$ then the posterior will have a uniform shape.

Comment: @silent_spec but this is what the answer says, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are parameters of the prior.

Comment: @Tim what I meant is if we leave $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as the parameters of a uniform prior ($\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 1$) then the posterior will also be uniform between $k$ and $N-n+k$, which seems undesirable as the shape of the posterior is not being determined by the likelihood of the data.