# beta-binomial as conjugate to hypergeometric

Tags: bayesian, conjugate-prior

According to the table of conjugate distributions on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions), the hypergeometric distribution has as conjugate prior a beta-binomial distribution, where the parameter of interest is "$M$, the number of target members." I interpret "target members" to mean, I am modeling as hypergeometric the number of blue balls in a sample from an urn containing $N$ total balls of which $M$ are blue, $N-M$ non-blue.

But then I cannot make sense of the claim of conjugacy. After the data is observed, say $b$ blue balls in the sample, then it is known that $M>b$. But a beta-binomial distribution is supported on $0,...,F$ (for some parameter $F$). So how can the posterior for $M$ also be beta-binomial?

Comment: I may be wrong but it looks to me like that there is a slight misunderstanding. Hypergeometric distribution describes the probability of drawing $k$ blue balls out of $n$ draws (without replacement) from an urn containing $N$ balls out of which $M$ are blue. It is not the probability distribution over $M$, the number of blue balls in the urn.

Comment: @MossMurderer No, this is a bayesian setup.

Answer (score 16):

The problem with the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions) and the reference therein (Fink D., 1997) is that there is some key information missing.

Specifically, the given posterior is for $M-x$ (*i.e.* the number of *target* individuals in the population shifted by the number observed in the sample), not for $M$. Furthermore, the posterior parameter corresponding to the number of observations is missing and should be $N-n$ (*i.e.* the population size minus the sample size). These two corrections fixes the support problem that you correctly noticed, as shown below.

Suppose that $0 \leq X \leq n$ is the number of *target*
individuals in a sample of size $n$ from a population of size $N$ with
$0 \leq M \leq N$ total *target* individuals.

Then, $X \sim \text{HG}(n, M, N)$ with support in $[\max(0, n-N+M), \min(n, M)]$.

If $M \sim \text{BB}(N, \alpha, \beta)$ is the prior distribution of $M$, the posterior distribution for $M - x$ is also Beta-Binomial-distributed:
$$M - x\,|\,x,\alpha,\beta \sim \text{BB}(N-n, \alpha + x, \beta + n - x)$$

If you write the probability mass function for $M$ you will find @Tim's answer above.

As an illustration, for $N = 20$ and $n = 10$, let's assume a non-informative prior distribution for $M$ with $M \sim \text{BB}(N, .5, .5)$.
Suppose that we observe $x = 9$.

```r
library(extraDistr)
library(tidyverse)
N = 20
n = 10
a0 <- b0 <- .5
x <- 9
data.frame(
  m = 0:N
) %>% 
  mutate(
    prior = dbbinom(m, size = N, alpha = a0, beta = b0),
    post = dbbinom(m-x, size = N-n, a0+x, b0+n-x)
  ) %>% 
  gather(key, dens, -m) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(m, dens, col = key)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Note that the posterior support is correctly [*x*, *N* − *n* + *x*].

> Dyer, D. and Pierce, R.L. (1993). On the Choice of the Prior
>   Distribution in Hypergeometric Sampling. Communications in Statistics
>   - Theory and Methods, 22(8), 2125-2146.

Answer (score 5):

Hypergeometric distribution describes sampling without replacement from the urn containing $N$ balls, out of which $M \le N$ are target balls, let's say blue. The conjugate beta-binomial prior distribution leads to posterior distribution for unknown $M \in \{x,x+1,\dots,N-n+x\}$ in form

$$
f(M\mid x,N,\alpha,\beta) = {N-n \choose M-x}
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+M)\,\Gamma(\beta+N-x)\,\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+n)}{\Gamma(\alpha+x)\,\Gamma(\beta+n-x)\,\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+N)}
$$

as described in

> Dyer, D. and Pierce, R.L. (1993). On the Choice of the Prior
>   Distribution in Hypergeometric Sampling. Communications in Statistics
>   - Theory and Methods, 22(8), 2125-2146.

Comment: I agree it makes sense to have the prior distribution on $M$ be beta-binomial. What doesn't make sense to me is that the posterior is also beta-binomial (because of the different supports issue mentioned in the question).

Comment: @Hasse1987 I don't understand what do you mean, the support is $0,1,\dots,N$, where BB distribution is parametrized by $\alpha,\beta,N$, where $N$ is known population size.

Comment: But the posterior distribution of $M$ cannot have that support. After the data is observed you know there are at least $b$ target members. So the support of the posterior is contained on $b,\ldots,N,$ right?

Comment: @Hasse1987 *a priori* it has $0,\dots,N$ support, after you observe some data it gets centered on more realistic values.

Comment: Of course. The point is that those "more realistic values" preclude a beta-binomial distribution.

Comment: @Hasse1987 sorry, the description in Wikipedia is unclear and didn't have time to read it carefully, please check my edit, the reference I quote and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269538/hypergeometric-distribution-when-k-is-unknown/269586#269586

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment: the formula given by @Tom is not correct, the correct formula is :

$$
f(M\mid x,N,\alpha,\beta) = {N-n \choose M-x}
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+M)\,\Gamma(\beta+N-M)\,\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+n)}{\Gamma(\alpha+x)\,\Gamma(\beta+n-x)\,\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+N)}
$$

The formula is also wrong in the reference:

> Dyer, D. and Pierce, R.L. (1993). On the Choice of the Prior
> Distribution in Hypergeometric Sampling. Communications in Statistics
>
> - Theory and Methods, 22(8), 2125-2146.

at p. 2131. It is clearly a typo because on the same page, few lines below, that formula (in its correct form) is used to derive equation (3.1.3)