# Is There a Conjugate Prior for a Multivariate Hypergeometric Likelihood?

Tags: conjugate-prior, hypergeometric-distribution

I am working on a problem using a [multivariate hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution) likelihood. The multivariate hypergeometric distribution does not belong to the exponential family of distributions, so (to my knowledge) we cannot guarantee that a conjugate prior exists.

However, Wikipedia claims on [its page about conjugate priors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) that the univariate hypergeometric distribution is conjugate with a beta binomial. [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311088/beta-binomial-as-conjugate-to-hypergeometric) shows that the posterior in the univariate case is for M-x, the "number of target individuals in the population shifted by the number observed in the sample".

Does the multivariate hypergeometic distribution have a conjugate prior? My hunch is that it would be the multivariate form of the beta-binomial, the dirichlet-multinomial. However, I don't know how to show that analytically. If it does have a conjugate prior, what would the posterior's hyper-parameters be?

Comment: What are the parameters of the multivariate hypergeometric on which you want to use a conjugate prior? Using [the standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution), with the $K_i$'s being the parameters there is no conjugate prior.

Comment: The $K_i$'s would be the parameters. Is there a simple explanation as to why? Or has one just not been found yet?

Comment: As you wrote, this distribution is not from an exponential family, hence cannot enjoy a conjugate prior.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this compendium of conjugate priors](https://www.johndcook.com/CompendiumOfConjugatePriors.pdf), the prior for the multivariate hypergeometric distribution's parameters is a Dirichlet-Multinomial distribution.

(The fact that the hypergeometric distribution does not belong to the exponential family does not preclude the possibility for conjugate prior. Simply, its existence is not guaranteed.)