# Hypergeometric CDF in R

Tags: r, distributions, reliability

I'm working on a reliability problem, and I've run into a snag. I have a population of 300 widgets. From that population, I took a random sample of 10 and 1 turned out to be bad. What I'd like to know (and plot) is what fraction of the remaining 290 should I expect to be flawed and (separately) the probability of finding n or more bad units as I keep sampling. I've tried fooling around with `phiper`, but I clearly don't understand what I need to be doing (since I don't know how much of the total population is flawed to begin with).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/371145/214015) CV answer.

For `N=300`, `n=10`, and `x=1`, a `BetaBin(N,0.5,0.5)` prior would result in a Beta-Binomial posterior distribution on `M-x` (the number of bad widgets in the remaining 290):

`BetaBin(300 - 10, 1 + 0.5, 10 - 1 + 0.5)`

As a function:

```
pBBpost <- function(N, n, x, a = 0.5, b = 0.5) {
  N_n <- N - n
  M_x <- 0:N_n
  cumsum(exp(lgamma(N_n + 1) + lgamma(a + b + n) - lgamma(N_n + a + b + n) - lgamma(a + x) - lgamma(b + n - x) + lgamma(M_x + a + x) + lgamma(N - M_x + b - x) - lgamma(M_x + 1) - lgamma(N_n - M_x + 1)))
}

N <- 300L
n <- 10L
x <- 1L
plot(0:(N - n), pBBpost(N, n, x), xlab = "Bad widgets remaining", ylab = "CDF")
```

[image]