# Estimating Size of a Set based on three or more Overlapping Subsets

Tags: estimation, capture-mark-recapture

What's the solution to the [capture-recapture](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137331/estimating-size-of-a-set-based-on-two-overlapping-subsets?rq=1) problem with 3 or more overlapping subsets, not just 2, as in the standard version of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

See the [Schnabel method](http://oak.snr.missouri.edu/nr3110/topics/schnabel.php) which is basically a weighted average of each of the Peterson estimates.